# Sending a small number of targeted emails, is it spamming?

Tags: email, marketing, bulk-email

I have a directory website and I want to send focused emails, a small amount, less than 50 a month, to some of the businesses on my directory that get many visitors.
The intention is to let them know many people are viewing their page and encourage them to update it and post information on it.

How can I send this small number of emails without being targeted as spam?

Also, should I send it from an email with the website's domain or will it better to send from a personal email? That way at least if email is tagged as spam sometimes it won't hurt the website's reputation, is this true?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, an email is not a spam if :

- user of your directory accepted to receive emails from your site.
- your email is relevant for user

In your case, I think your emails won't considered as spam.

It's better if you send emails from your website domain email because it's more professional (my opinion again) and I don't believe emails considered as spam can hurt website reputation if your sent emails aren't really spam.